# what is $d(y/x)$ in $ d\log(y/x)=\frac{d(y/x)}{(y/x)}$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

For example what is meant by $d(y/x)$ in right hand numerator in the following?

$$ d\log(y/x)=\frac{d(y/x)}{(y/x)}$$

Is the same as $\frac{dy}{dx}$? If not, what does it mean?

Comment: let $z=y/x$, what is $d\, \log z$?

Comment: I dont know, care to elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not the same

$$
{\rm d}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) = \frac{{\rm d}y}{x} - \frac{y}{x^2}{\rm d}x \not= \frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x}
$$

Comment: So what is it? What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

This needs some context. Let $u = \frac yx$. Your formula, reads $d\log(u) = \frac{du}u$.

If you are reading this in the context of differential geometry, then $d \log(u)$ is a differential form and is given by
$$ d\log(u) = \frac{\partial \log(u)}{\partial u} du = \frac{du}u.$$
If this is in the context of ordinary calculus, it is a lazy way of writing $(\log(u))' = \frac{u'}u$, where the prime sign is a derivative with respect to an independent variable that both $x$ and $y$ depend on.